# Should I use utf-8 or base64 to encode email in url parameter?

Tags: rest, url

Should I use utf-8 or base64 to encode email in url parameter?

As far as I am aware base64 is for binary data encoding while utf-8 is to encode text. So I assume utf-8 is the right answer? However I see lots of cases where emails are required to be encoded in base64.

I was just wondering what was best practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither. URL parameters are encoded using [percent-encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).